# The sun hasn't risen or hadn't risen?

Tags: present-perfect, past-perfect, past-simple

> When I got up at 4:30 this morning, I could still see the stars in the sky. The sun _____ yet.
>
> a. hasn't risen
>   b. didn't rise
>   c. hadn't risen

I believe it is C because we are talking about something in the past, right?

Comment: What you have to consider is that it is expected (certain) that the sun will rise soon. This tie-up should keep you in the present perfect tense.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, yes. *Hasn't* would be present tense. For example, something like this:

> I am already up at 4:30 in the morning! I can still see the stars in the sky. The sun hasn’t risen yet.

Comment: Actually the OP chose past perfect. In any case, you should explain why your answer is the correct one.